# Solr OR queries with weight

Tags: solr

How in Solr use weigth of query?

Sample query from user "one two three"

In result

first all documents with "one two three"

next all documents with "one two"

next all documents with "two three"

next all documents with "one three"

next all documents with "one"

next all documents with "two"

next all documents with "three"

I try use next

"+one +two +three"^100

OR "+one +two"^50

OR "+two +three"^50

OR "+one three"^50

OR "+one"^10

OR "+two"^10

OR "+three"^10

No effect

Comment: This is the default behavior - as long as more terms match, the score will be higher for those where the most terms match. What does your _actual_ query look like where that doesn't happen?

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks, really solr results is correct